# Using pandas, return min price value of product from 4 different dataframes. Some products are common

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm creating a python script with pandas and NumPy to help me automate the boring stuff in excel.

Each day, we receive 4 pricelists by different suppliers in XLSX/CSV files that contain price and availability. Some of our SKUs are common across those files.

So far I have made all 4 data frames and the main one that contains all our SKUs. The script checks if a product is available on at least one supplier and creates a new column with values Available & N/A.

Below is a sample of the data frames. I need help to create 2 new columns, one that reports the best price and one that reports which supplier offered that price.

```
DF-Main
|SKU|Product |Supp 1 Material No|Supp 2 Material No|Column I Made|Best Price|By Supplier?
|--| --- | --- | --- |---|---|---|
|1 |Gigabyte RTX 2060 OC 6GB|GV-N2060OC-6GD|VGA5420|Available| 370 | Supplier 2
|2 |Gigabyte RTX 3060 Eagle OC 12GB|GV-N3060EAGLE OC-12GD|VGA6056|N/A
|3 |Ryzen 5 5600X AM4 BOX |100-100000065BOX|CPU0679|Available|250|Supplier 1

DF1
|Their SKU|Product |Availability|Price|
|--| --- | --- | --- |
GV-N2060OC-6GD|Gigabyte RTX 2060 OC 6GB|Yes|400
GV-N3060EAGLE OC-12GD|Gigabyte RTX 3060 Eagle OC 12GB|No
100-100000065BOX|Ryzen 5 5600X AM4 BOX |Yes|250

DF2
|Their SKU|Product |Availability|Price|
|--| --- | --- | --- |
VGA5420|Gigabyte RTX 2060 OC 6GB|Yes|370
VGA6056|Gigabyte RTX 3060 Eagle OC 12GB|No
CPU0679|Ryzen 5 5600X AM4 BOX|Yes|320
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide us some sample data and expected output.

Comment: The approach I would take is to make sure there is a supplier column in each of the four dataframes (these will be the same value for each) then concat the 4 dataframes together. That will give you a dataframe with all the possible suppliers and their prices for every SKU. Then you will want to do a Pandas groupby SKU. Find the minimum price, and from there it is relatively straight forward to get the supplier with that price.